# open throat = less air = less voice loss?

Tags: voice, vocal-cords, voice-training

I often experience voice loss after singing. I was told this can be caused by too much air through the vocal cords, which irritates them. Are they really related? And is there a relation between "amount of air" and "open throat" too?

I figured out the following equation:

open throat = less air = less voice loss

Is that equation correct? I was also told about "glottal compression" and I suspected this was related to "open throat" as well.

Is there any relation between these concept? If so, then it would be very very important to have an "open throat" to also fix a certain number of other issues with the voice.

Answer (score 1):

"Open throat" is more concerned with setting up the resonances well in the mouth.  Optimally this will increase the resistance the vocal folds work against and thus reduce their movement for equal volume.  However, that does not really concern air use which is rather governed by the size of the vocal gap.

Both "open throat" and "good closure" (less air) are part of healthy phonation and should be aimed for but they are mostly orthogonal and it's actually an additional challenge to aim for both at once.

So your equation, while indeed concerning itself with "good" things, is mostly gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing any problem at all, be it soreness, voice loss, or whatever,  stop singing entirely until you can get evaluated by a professional voice teacher.  Not only are you risking long-term physical damage, but you are also at risk of getting into bad habits; those can be difficult to retrain.